# Unable to find etc folder in hadoop 2.6.5 installation

Tags: hadoop, installation

I am trying to install hadoop 2.6.5 in my linux system but unable to find etc folder which contains the config and env files. I have untared the tar file . File and directeries listing in the hadoop folder are

```
/home/tcs>cd hadoop
/home/tcs/hadoop>ls -ltr
total 192

-rw-rw-r--  1 tcs tcs  1366 Jul 23  2015 README.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tcs tcs 14978 Sep 20  2016 NOTICE.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tcs tcs 84853 Sep 20  2016 LICENSE.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tcs tcs 12091 Sep 20  2016 BUILDING.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tcs tcs 18121 Sep 20  2016 pom.xml
drwxrwxr-x  3 tcs tcs  4096 Mar  9 18:00 hadoop-project
drwxrwxr-x  3 tcs tcs  4096 Mar  9 18:00 hadoop-assemblies
drwxrwxr-x  3 tcs tcs  4096 Mar  9 18:00 hadoop-yarn-project
drwxrwxr-x 10 tcs tcs  4096 Mar  9 18:00 hadoop-common-project
drwxrwxr-x  2 tcs tcs  4096 Mar  9 18:00 hadoop-dist
drwxrwxr-x  2 tcs tcs  4096 Mar  9 18:00 hadoop-client
drwxrwxr-x  3 tcs tcs  4096 Mar  9 18:00 dev-support
drwxrwxr-x  9 tcs tcs  4096 Mar  9 18:00 hadoop-mapreduce-project
drwxrwxr-x  2 tcs tcs  4096 Mar  9 18:00 hadoop-project-dist
drwxrwxr-x  6 tcs tcs  4096 Mar  9 18:00 hadoop-hdfs-project
drwxrwxr-x  2 tcs tcs  4096 Mar  9 18:00 hadoop-build-tools
drwxrwxr-x 15 tcs tcs  4096 Mar  9 18:00 hadoop-tools
drwxrwxr-x  2 tcs tcs  4096 Mar  9 18:00 hadoop-minicluster
drwxrwxr-x  3 tcs tcs  4096 Mar  9 18:00 hadoop-maven-plugins
```

please help

Comment: What have you downloaded is hadoop sources. You can build from them hadoop distribution or you can download ready binary distribution.

Comment: I agree with @Luk. Download the binary from: http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html

Answer (score 2):

What have you downloaded is hadoop sources. You can build from them hadoop distribution or you can download ready binary distribution.
You can find them for example here: http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html